# Apache Web Server character encoding

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, tomcat6, charset

I've recently transferred my webapp from my localhost (LH) to a VPS, and have had hebrew chars-encoding probs since. Whenever I send a request with a heb-char it results in "?????" saved to the DB.

My LH config was tomcat6, MySQL, and centOS 6.2, opened to the web.  In the VPS env I'm behind an Apache Web Server, and the rest is quite the same (though I haven't done anything to its installation). 
Please note I already have had this problem before, on my LH when the request was sent from IE/chrome (not FF!). The solution was to apply a filter on the the context and change the char-type to UTF-8.

My webapp content char-encode is utf-8, MySql server set to utf8 using **charset utf8;**, and my centOS set to iw_IL.UTF8 using **export LANG=iw_IL.UTF8**. When I use **locale** the bash output seems to be set correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your database, table and column charset?

Comment: I guess you need to send a header information : 
http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in my.cnf and php.ini that all the connections are encoded with utf8

**my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
default-character-set=utf8
default-collation=utf8_general_ci
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'

[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

**php.ini**

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -2):

just leave empty 'default_charset' in WHM :::::: default_charset =''

p.s. In WHM go --------) Home »Service Configuration »PHP Configuration Editor ----) click 'Advanced Mode' ----) find 'default_charset' and leave it blank ---- just nothing, not utf8, not ISO

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on your answer? Which configuration file? It would prove valuable for future users searching for solutions.

Comment: In WHM go --------) Home »Service Configuration »PHP Configuration Editor ----) click 'Advanced Mode' ----) find 'default_charset' and leave it blank ---- just nothing, not utf8, not ISO